# Triggering onVisible on a Properties Pane in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have a piece of code that clears a collection when the Powerapp/Properties Panel of a Sharepoint Online Document List is opened.

Right, now the onVisible only runs the first time I open the Panel.  If I close it and open another document with it, the onVisible does not run again.

Essentially, looking for a way to detect if a new Document Properties Panel has been opened and run a bit of code.

I don't believe ContextVariables work either, as it is the same App/Same Screen that opens.

Is there a way to detect a change to the "Panels" Input ID variable perhaps?
Is there a way to detect if the "record" the Panel just opened changes? (OnSuccess doesn't seem to catch it)

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While does doesn't answer the onVisible exactly, I created two different workarounds.

Option 1:  Use a Timer to check the ID of the sharepoint list item, and compare every x seconds.
Option 2:  Reset the variable on the OnSuccess of the Form Control and also on the OnCancel of the App Control.  (Recommended)